# Write to a PDF using JS (pdfform.js)

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I need to make an update to a script that is using pdfform.js in order to take data from html inputs and pass them into a fillable pdf file.

Basically all I need to do is to update the PDF file for the year 2022.
The problem is that my new PDF doesn't have fields where I can write like the old one:

PDF that has fillable inputs:
[old pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMyiI.png)

My new PDF:
[new pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbxeb.png)

I tried to add fields to my new pdf using Adobe Acrobat but the script is not able to write to them. I don't know exactly how to add the fields in order to have the same reference as the old ones.

```js
<script type = "text/javascript"
src = "pdfform.pdf_js.dist.js" > < /script>
 < script > $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#descarca-pdf").on("click", function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var a = new XMLHttpRequest;
            a.open("GET", "Formular-230_Habitat-for-Humanity-Romania-2.pdf", !0), a.responseType = "arraybuffer", a.onload = function() {
                if (200 == this.status) {
                    var a = this.response,
                        e = {
                            cnp: [$("#form-cnp").val()],
                            initiala: [$("#form-initiala").val()],
                            prenume: [$("#form-prenume").val()],
                            numar: [$("#form-numar").val()],
                            nume: [$("#form-nume").val()],
                            scara: [$("#form-scara").val()],
                            etaj: [$("#form-etaj").val()],
                            apartament: [$("#form-apartament").val()],
                            bloc: [$("#form-bloc").val()],
                            judet: [$("#form-judet").val()],
                            localitate: [$("#form-localitate").val()],
                            codpostal: [$("#form-codpostal").val()],
                            email: [$("#form-email").val()],
                            telefon: [$("#form-telefon").val()],
                            strada: [$("#form-strada").val()],
                            fax: [$("#form-fax").val()]
                        },
                        o = pdfform().transform(a, e),
                        t = new Blob([o], {
                            type: "application/pdf"
                        }),
                        r = document.createElement("a");
                    r.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(t), r.download = "Formular_230_Habitat_for_Humanity_Romania.pdf", r.click()
                } else on_error("failed to load URL (code: " + this.status + ")")
            }, a.send()
        })
    }); < /script>
```

Does anyone know any tool that I can use for this?

Comment: The pdf is a governmental document and I cannot modify it. Somehow the previous team of developers managed to add input fields on top of it and referenced them with the js code. I dont know exactly how I can make that reference, but I was able to add inputs on top of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are trying to update a Government Form 230 which used to look like this
[image]

And you say you need to update those field for this year HOWEVER the  Current Form uses a totally different structure, like this

[image]

**Here we can see the difference in the two sets of field tags**

[image]

The XFDF data fields structure as published can be found at
https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Declaratii_R/AplicatiiDec/structura_B230_D230_2020_27032020.pdf
and https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Declaratii_R/AplicatiiDec/structura_B230_D230_2022_12012022.pdf

The forms structure may be used for customised versions with a java library and both years forms have their own personalized .jars for each structure, so it is best to use the official ANAF J Soft available online.

You provide a sample of a modified custom version which has been dumbed down to be part flattened and part not ! thus to my view would not be compatible with your declaration it must match the government XFA format, however it was initially generated or modified using Adobe Forms Library Code, so has working fields in one part area, but they are not XFA structure like the official ANAF version they are declared as ***"You cannot save data...Please print..."*** to be simply printed and scanned as if it was a basic paper copy without intelligent fields, which defeats the whole reason for it being a fillable form in the first place. You may just as well use a word doc or any other editor form.

OK on looking through many ***different modified D230's including yours*** they seem to be from the same source "Codruţ Popa" who I assume is an ANAF designer so best to get a newer copy from them.

[image]

Comment: this make sense but I need to use the same procedure like in the past. On the website the JS code is reading the PDF that looks similar with this: https://www.hospice.ro/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/hcs-declaratia-230-2022-1.pdf As you can see the other developers took the PDF from ANAF and then somehow they added forms to it that are "readable" by the JS script. I need to do now the same but for another association.

Comment: What software you used to get this interface? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWZdt.png